# How to define a macro containing if without closing fi, and another macro containing the closing fi

Tags: macros, conditionals, ifthenelse

I am working on a LaTeX document and writing at several locations. For faster compiling, I have surrounded some sections with `\iffalse, \fi` constructs.
When I proof-read the document at the end of the day, I would like to include all those commented parts to be compiled without manually commenting the `\iffalse, \fi`.
So I tried to define macros, but LaTeX complains, probably because the `\iffalse` needs to be followed by a `\fi` in the command definition.
Is there a way to achieve this, i.e. not define a command that must by itself contain syntactically correct code, but just a macro that is substituted everywhere?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\iffalsePrint}{\iffalse}
\newcommand{\fiPrint}{\fi}
% at the end of the day, enable all sections for printing, change this in a single place here
% \newcommand{\iffalsePrint}{}
% \newcommand{\fiPrint}{}

\begin{document}

\iffalsePrint
text to appear when above is uncommented
\fiPrint

another text

\iffalsePrint
second text
\fiPrint

third text

\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use the standard `\newif\ifPrint` command that is designed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tex has seen `\iffalse` it doesn't matter how the macros are defined as they are never expanded so your `\fiPrint` can not work, you could use `\let\fiPrint\fi`  so that it is seen as `\fi` but there will still be issues with nested cases.

the standard mechanism is to use

```
\newif\ifPrint`
```

To declare the commands then surround your conditional blocks with

```
\ifPrint
conditional text here
\fi
```

The block will be used or skipped depending whether you execute `\Printtrue` or `\Printfalse` before that point to set the state of the boolean test.